# Oracle - Copy column to another table with condition

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to copy one column from TABLE A to TABLE B.
I saw some solution online but none of them shows how to add a condition.

```
TABLE A:

TABLE_A_ID
COLUMN_TO_COPY


TABLE B:

TABLE_B_ID
TABLE_A_FK
NEW_COLUMN
```

I want to copy COLUMN_TO_COPY to NEW_COLUMN but where TABLE_A_ID = TABLE_A_FK

I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_B (NEW_COLUMN )
    SELECT COLUMN_TO_COPY 
    FROM TABLE_A
    WHERE TABLE_A_ID = TABLE_A_FK
```

But the query doesn't know what TABLE_A_FK is.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want an *update* here, not an insert:

```
UPDATE TABLE_B b
SET NEW_COLUMN = (SELECT COLUMN_TO_COPY FROM TABLE_A a WHERE a.TABLE_A_ID = b.TABLE_A_FK);
```

If you only want to make an update where an actual match happens between the two tables, then add an exists clause:

```
UPDATE TABLE_B b
SET NEW_COLUMN = (SELECT COLUMN_TO_COPY FROM TABLE_A a WHERE a.TABLE_A_ID = b.TABLE_A_FK)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_A a WHERE a.TABLE_A_ID = b.TABLE_A_FK);
```

Comment: I am only faster than light in a vacuum.  Otherwise, I'm a bit slower `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

Another way of achieving the desired result is to use the `MERGE` statement as follows:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE_B B 
USING ( SELECT * FROM TABLE_A) A 
ON ( A.TABLE_A_ID = B.TABLE_A_FK )
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET B.NEW_COLUMN = A.COLUMN_TO_COPY;
```

Cheers!!